# How do I update to StructureMap 3.x while staying on NServiceBus 4.x?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nservicebus, structuremap, nservicebus4

I want to upgrade to StructureMap 3.x on my MVC project, but I'm stuck on NServiceBus 4.x because the 5.x license terms do not make sense for our limited usage.  The MVC project is send-only.

How can I upgrade StructureMap while leaving NSB 4.x in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Configure
    .With()
    .StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container)
```

Use the default container:

```
Configure
    .With()
    .DefaultBuilder()
```

Because you're no longer passing `ObjectFactory.Container` through to NServiceBus, you'll need to tell StructureMap how to fulfill `IBus` as a dependency for, e.g. your MVC controllers:

```
x.For<NServiceBus.IBus>()
    .Use(() => Configure
        .Instance
        .CreateBus()
        .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install())
    );
```

If you have something that NServiceBus needs to create, e.g. something that implements `IMutateOutgoingMessages` and your message mutator has dependencies, then you'll have to tell NServiceBus how to resolve those dependencies:

```
Configure
    .Instance
    .Configurer
    .ConfigureComponent(
        () => new MessageMutator(new MessageMutatorDependency()),
        DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question on the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/particularsoftware/VYOONWu91ME/sCtNvQuYffkJ).  The answer at the time was that this configuration is not supported, and AFAIK that hasn't changed.

I would recommend dropping an email to Particular and see if you can work something out regarding licensing if this is a showstopper for your project.

Comment: Because the endpoint is send-only I'm thinking there's a way around it.  I don't need to invoke handlers.

Comment: In that case just leave the internal container as is and just register the IBus in your own SM container?